# Symplectic structure on moduli space of holomorphic Abelian differentials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, sg.symplectic-geometry, moduli-spaces

I've heard a "symplectic structure" referred to on the moduli space of holomorphic Abelian differentials by numerous people / sources. I do not know how to interpret this - I am looking for references.

Comment: Might they have said "holomorphic quadratic differentials" rather than "holomorphic Abelian differentials"?  The geometric vector bundle over the moduli space of curves whose fibers are vector spaces of holomorphic quadratic differentials is the cotangent bundle of the moduli space of curves, thus has a natural symplectic structure.